# Why does the paragraph block automatically add class?

Tags: block-editor

I want to have this paragraph block:

```
<p>Normal text <span class=""has-h-3-font-size">Big text</span> Normal text</p>
```

However it always converts to:

```
<p class=""has-h-3-font-size">Normal text <span class=""has-h-3-font-size">Big text</span> Normal text</p>
```

I have to use the HTML block to stop this.

Why does this happen? The article [Paragraph Block | WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/article/paragraph-block/) doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: How are you inserting the `<span>` into the paragraph block?

Comment: You have a typo. You have an extra quote mark

Comment: @kero I edit it as HTML

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks. However, it still injects an empty class in p: `<p class="">`. Do you know why is that?